# Change the code and include filename in output

Tags: powershell

I have a many text files in a folder with following content:

```
2023008.500   3511920.5720   2840600.1723   4488087.1798  0.0003 0.0003 0.0004 F
2023009.500   3511920.5462   2840600.1589   4488087.1600  0.0164 0.0034 0.0094 F
2023010.500   3511920.5707   2840600.1646   4488087.1692  0.0003 0.0003 0.0004 F
2023011.500   3511920.5717   2840600.1649   4488087.1734  0.0003 0.0003 0.0004 F
2023012.500   3511920.6336   2840600.1661   4488087.1217  0.0144 0.0026 0.0086 F
```

I would like to get filename and line from file where column [4] greater than 0.01. I create a code. It's work, but don't get a filename, because Get-Content command create one output from all files without filenames.

```
(& {
    foreach ($line in Get-Content -Path .\*SMAN_2023.xyz)
    {
        $columns = $line -split '\s+'
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        date = $columns[0]
            dX = $columns[4]
            dY = $columns[5]
        dZ = $columns[6]
        }
    } 
} | where-object{$_.dX -gt 0.01} | Out-String).Trim() | Out-File -FilePath output.txt -NoNewline
```

I try to change the code with Get-ChildItem commandlet but ... I have no idea how to implement old code into new.

```
$InputFolder = ".\"
$OutputFile = ".\output1.txt"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $InputFolder | Where-Object { $_.FullName -like "*SMAN_2023.xyz"}
Foreach ($File in $Files) {
  foreach ($line in Get-Content $File.FullName )
    {
        $columns = $line -split '\s+'
        [PSCustomObject]@{
        filename = $filename
        date = $columns[0]
            dX = $columns[4]
            dY = $columns[5]
            dZ = $columns[6] }
        }
```

Can someone help me?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can take advantage of the fact that [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content) decorates each line from the file being read it outputs with a `.PSPath` property that contains the file's full path:

```bash
Get-Content -Path .\*SMAN_2023.xyz |
 Where-Object { [double] (-split $_)[4] -gt 0.01 } | 
 ForEach-Object {
   [pscustomobject] @{
     File = $_.PSPath
     Line = $_
   }
 } |
 Export-Csv output.csv
```

Note:

- `[double] (-split $_)[4] -gt 0.01` is a simpler way to check the 5th whitespace separated column value - interpreted as a *number* via cast `[double]` - against a threshold; the *unary* form of the [`-split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Split) operator implicitly splits by any nonempty run of whitespace (and additionally ignores leading and trailing whitespace).
- The [`ForEach-Object`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/foreach-object) call constructs a `[pscustomobject]` instance for each matching line that contains both that line and the full path of the file of origin.
- Because it is better to save this information in a *structured* text format, [`Export-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/export-csv) is used to create a CSV file, instead of [`Out-File`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/out-file), which would create a *plain-text* file that contains the *for-display*-formatted representation of its input objects.